# In SQL, how do I change the format a column of dates (which are currently a text datatype) to a different format?

Tags: sql

This is my first question here so apologies if I don't give enough info, please feel free to correct anything that is amiss.

In SQL I have a column labelled "date" with 2500 entries in the format of "2014-01-25T05:00:00Z". It is a text datatype. It is part of a table called concerts.

I need these dates to be in the the format '25 Jan 2014'.

All of the following attempts have produced errors:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,CAST(date AS DATE),106)
FROM concerts

 SELECT FORMAT(CAST(date AS DATE),106) FROM concerts
```

Comment: Store dates as a date type not as char. Please share the error message and add the tag for the dbms you are using.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: **Never**, ever store date values as varchar/text. Just don't